# Excel formula to check and see if a column is in ascending order

Tags: excel

I need a formula to check and see the the values in a given column are in ascending order or not.

True Example:
4
29
54
79
107
131
156
177

False Example:
4
29
104
79
107
186
156
177

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an array formula to accomplish this.

Let's assume you have data in `B4:B10`.

In whichever cell you want the `TRUE` or `FALSE` to appear, which will indicate whether a column is sorted by ascending or descending, place the following formula in the cell:

`=AND(B4:B9<=B5:B10)`

Instead of pressing enter like normal, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You will know if it is an array formula because you will see curly braces around it, such as:

[image]

What you are doing is, say you have a list of n values, you are evaluating the first value to the n-1 value and checking to see if they are in order, if they are all in order then `TRUE` is returned, if any are out of order then `FALSE` is returned.

Comment: Thank you! I also realize that this doesn't work with formula outputs. I had to copy the column and paste as values and convert to numbers so the array formula could see the values. This has helped me to ensure that invoices I had collated was in fact in the correct order.

Comment: It doesn't work on LibreOffice Calc. AND function only works with single value not the column.

Comment: I tried today (may/2021) and it worked on Libre Calc as well